# Manually select location, how to implement?

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm building an app in Ionic 3.4 that uses Geolocation to show a list of places in the Google Maps JS SDK. It works pretty neat, except for some devices, in which Cordova seems to have serious problems when retrieving the geolocation (at this moment, it only happens to my Xiaomi mi5s, Global MIUI 8).

This is a trouble, and there doesn't seem to be any fix for that. Then, if my petition throws a timeout after a few seconds, **I will enable a little formulary which permits the user to select his country, and then, city**.

For this, I need:

- Some kind of API that gives me all countries
- That same API should permit me go into a lower level and select the different localities/cities of that country, or even perform a search over them.
- When both things have been selected, the API should retrieve a geolocation I can pass to the map to show that place off.

I've been taking a look and I still don't know how I can do this... so, do you know some kind of API that can permit me this? A working example would be appreciated, too!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox), it has a search box which adds a marker onto the map when the user clicks on the searched result in the search box.

Comment: Really great! Thank you mate, I'm implementing this.